# no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'CandyBar' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')

Tags: c++

В ходе изучения языка по книге, при решении очередной задачи, я наткнулся на эту ошибку, понятия не имею, что она означает и как ее исправить... Главное дело, этот код работает в онлайн компиляторе без проблем, а в VS Code возникает ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее решить и что делать, чтобы с ней больше не сталкиваться?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct CandyBar {
    char name[30];
    float weight;
    int calories;
};

int main() {
    CandyBar* snack = new CandyBar[3];
    
    snack[0] = {"Mocha Monch", 2.3, 350};
    snack[1] = {"Uran", 1.2, 30000000};
    snack[2] = {"Barbaris", 1.3, 230};
    
    cout << "Name[0]: " << snack[0].name << " Weight[0]: " << snack[0].weight << " Calories[0]: " << snack[0].calories << endl;
    cout << "Name[1]: " << snack[1].name << " Weight[1]: " << snack[1].weight << " Calories[1]: " << snack[1].calories << endl;
    cout << "Name[2]: " << snack[2].name << " Weight[2]: " << snack[2].weight << " Calories[2]: " << snack[2].calories << endl;

    delete [] snack;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А каким компилятором пользуетесь? Какой стандарт указан? VS Code — среда, а не компилятор. В VC++ компилируется без проблем.

Comment: Друвний стандарт: `snack[0] = CandyBar("Mocha Monch", 2.3, 350);`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sWxnq6T9j

Comment: Дайте угадаю, Мак?

Comment: @Harry Насчет компилятора, скачивал последнюю версию mingw64 (gсс), стандарт с++14

Comment: @megorit не работает =(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня винда

Comment: Тогда откуда конкретно скачан компилятор? И откуда вы знаете, какой стандарт у вас выбран?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat скачивал отсюда: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat стандарт узнал с помощью команды std::cout << __cplusplus;

Comment: Так, и какое число напечаталось.  И что `g++ --version` печатает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat напечаталось 201402, команда печатает: g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Comment: Проблема в старом багованом компиляторе. GCC 8.1 - это не новый, последний сейчас - 13.1. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) читайте как его поставить.